# I can't join the college of winterhold

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I persuaded Faralda to let into the college and she told me to follow her, and I ran past and talked to the elf she was going to talk with. That didn't let me join but the quest marker was still above the elfs head. When I ran back to Faralda she was slowly making her way up the path lighting the candles but she stopped at the entrance. How can I fix this?

Comment: Save and reload, or reload a previous save

Comment: Go to a far away location, rest for 30 days to reset the area, and go back.

Answer (score 4):

According [to this site's](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/College_of_Winterhold_(Skyrim)) bugs section, "As of Patch 1.3 the "Visit the College of Winterhold" quest may not complete if the persuasion or Dragonborn dialogue options are used." So just reload to a save before persuaded Faralda and cast the spell on the symbl of the college on the ground.